# How to implement weather functionality in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing weather applciation for iphone but dont know which api i have to used.
And how to implement this things.

Please give me some advice for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For weather better use Yahoo Weather Forecast
It gives forecast based on WOEID of a particular place
Once check out: http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Comment: I am using below url http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2295402 but it gives toda and tomorrow weather information..I want 7 days weather information so what i have to do it

Comment: @JohnWhite: Check this http://www.worldweatheronline.com/premium-weather.aspx?menu=marine but u have to pay for it. But you can use the trail available for 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the following link for getting weather forecast.

[Weather online](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx)

The feed returns data in the form of JSON/XML.

Just follow the intructions and later you can use NSXMLParser or JSON parsing for parsing the data

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Google api](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=paris) used to get the weather information. This is an XML Document you have to parse this by using the [NSXML Parser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: They killed this api as of August 28